# Reading and writing matching patterns in text files

Tags: regex, text, awk, pattern-matching

I have a big log file with text like the following:

```
C:\>mml "hgsdp:imsi=404421896673168, all;" | findstr CSP
C:\>mml "hgsdp:imsi=404421911915615, all;" | findstr CSP
RSA-5        PDPCP-5      CSP-42       REDMCH-1

C:\>mml "hgsdp:imsi=404421800964442, all;" | findstr CSP
BS3G-1       RSA-5        PDPCP-5      CSP-40

C:\>mml "hgsdp:imsi=404421737909153, all;" | findstr CSP
C:\>mml "hgsdp:imsi=404421852512826, all;" | findstr CSP
RSA-5        PDPCP-5      CSP-21       REDMCH-1
```

I am interested in grabbing the CSP-### value which comes under "imsi=4044##" and write in another file along with the corresponding 4044## number. 
So the final output for the sample would be:

```
404421896673168 NIL
404421911915615 CSP-42
404421800964442 CSP-40
404421737909153 NIL
404421852512826 CSP-21
```

I have tried using awk but cannot make it work:

```
awk '/4044%/{N=NR+1;next} NR==N{print $3}' csp.log > output.txt
```

Appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]:=,]+' '/findstr CSP/ && $4=="imsi" {
  if (imsi != "")
     print imsi, "NIL"
  imsi=$5
  next
}
/CSP-/ {
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i ~ /CSP-/)
         break
   print imsi, $i
   imsi=""
}' file

404421896673168 NIL
404421911915615 CSP-42
404421800964442 CSP-40
404421737909153 NIL
404421852512826 CSP-21
```

Comment: It works great anubhava. Only concern is that the "4044##" is sometimes repeated and it has CSP-## only in one occurrance. So when I run the awk it gives me both NIL as well CSP-## value for the same 4044###. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This awk command is not really searching for `4044...` strings. It just gets `$5` from the line. I've shown my output for the sample data in question it seems to be fine

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.